# Query that selects all home fixtures by date in descending order

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mariadb

This the QUERY I have done using normal WHERE condition

```
SELECT  FIXTURE.Fixture_ID, FIXTURE.Game_Date, TEAM.Team_Name,
        OPPONENT.Opponent_Team_Name, FIXTURE.Results, FIXTURE.Score,
        FIXTURE.Location
    FROM  FIXTURE,TEAM,OPPONENT
    WHERE  FIXTURE.Location='Home'
      AND  FIXTURE.TM_ID = TEAM.Team_ID
      AND  FIXTURE.OPP_ID = OPPONENT.Opponent_ID
    GROUP BY  Game_Date
    ORDER BY  Game_Date DESC;
```

This the Same process done with JOIN, but yields error

```
SELECT  FIXTURE.Fixture_ID, FIXTURE.Game_Date, TEAM.Team_Name,
        OPPONENT.Opponent_Team_Name, FIXTURE.Results, FIXTURE.Score,
        FIXTURE.Location
    FROM  FIXTURE
    WHERE  FIXTURE.Location='Home'
    JOIN  TEAM  ON FIXTURE.TM_ID = TEAM.Team_ID
    JOIN  OPPONENT  ON FIXTURE.OPP_ID = OPPONENT.Opponent_ID
    GROUP BY  Game_Date
    ORDER BY  Game_Date DESC;
```

What am I doing wrong here ?. Please suggest the correct solution.

Thank you.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong here?` ... you didn't include your query as text in the question, and the image link is hard to read, so nobody will be able to help you.  _Edit_ your question and neatly type out/paste your SQL query, with the current and expected output.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here? Tim it's right. Anyways, the JOIN must go after FROM and before WHERE. Check it out

Comment: Worked like a charm @nacho...... Thanks a lot. How do I upvote your comment ?

Comment: I will put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The order of the JOIN and WHERE are incorrect, the JOIN must go after the FROM and before the WHERE like:

```
SELECT FIXTURE.Fixture_ID,
       FIXTURE.Game_Date,
       TEAM.Team_Name,
       OPPONENT.Opponent_Team_Name,
       FIXTURE.Results,
       FIXTURE.Score,
       FIXTURE.Location
FROM FIXTURE
     JOIN TEAM ON FIXTURE.TM_ID = TEAM.Team_ID
     JOIN OPPONENT ON FIXTURE.OPP_ID = OPPONENT.Opponent_ID
WHERE FIXTURE.Location='Home'
GROUP BY Game_Date
ORDER BY Game_Date DESC;
```